# Why type cast a void pointer?

Tags: c, types, casting, malloc

Being new to C, the only practical usage I have gotten out of void pointers is for versatile functions that may store different data types in a given pointer. Therefore I did not type-cast my pointer when doing memory allocation.

I have seen some code examples that sometimes use void pointers, but they get type-cast. Why is this useful? Why not directly create desired type of pointer instead of a void?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: You don't need to cast from `void*` because the language defines an automatic conversion from `void*` to any other type of pointer, but not all programmers are aware of this (not even all C book authors, unfortunately).

Comment: You have to cast a void pointer if you want to access its structure.(struct)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why use `void` pointers or why to cast them?

Comment: @larsmans More precisely, the C standard defines implicit compatibility between `void *` all **data** pointer types. Function pointers are out of the game (if, however, your system is POSIX, and why would any sane programmer use anything non-POSIX, then function pointers are compatible with `void *` too).

Comment: [This may be relevant here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: [It is “code”, not “codes.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context)

Answer (score 22):

There are two reasons for casting a void pointer to another type in C.

1. If you want to access something being pointed to by the pointer ( `*(int*)p = 42` )
2. If you are actually writing code in the common subset of C and C++, rather than "real" C. See also [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The reason for 1 should be obvious. Number two is because C++ disallows the implicit conversion from `void*` to other types, while C allows it.

Comment: But argument 2 is invalid: one should not compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @H2Co3: True, but sometimes you have code defined in header files in macros or inline functions which is meant to be usable in both C and C++ code which includes those headers.

Comment: @H2CO3 Nevertheless, some people do it. I was trying to explain the phenomenon, not justify it.

Comment: 3rd reason: You are forced by a brain-dead coding guideline. s/implicit cast/implicit conversion/

Comment: @undur: "I was just following orders" doesn't count. Good catch on the cast/conversion thing, though.

Comment: Reason 3: To tell people looking at your code that this area of memory is of that type, since `a->b = malloc(sizeof(*a->b))` doesn't tell anything while `a->b = (struct Monster*)malloc(sizeof(*a->b))` does.

Comment: @xryl669 Completely disagree! Record like **a->b = malloc(sizeof(*a->b))** tell you: allocating memory of size needed for **b** and assigning it to **b**. It is perfect and clear as for me. ;)

Answer (score 17):

You need to cast void pointers to something else if you want to dereference them, for instance you get a void pointer as a function parameter and you know for sure this is an integer:

```
void some_function(void * some_param) {
    int some_value = *some_param; /* won't work, you can't dereference a void pointer */
}

void some_function(void * some_param) {
    int some_value = *((int *) some_param); /* ok */
}
```

Comment: You don't *need to;* a more readable (preferred by me) approach is `int *tmp = param; int val = *tmp;`.

Comment: @H2CO3 You have to if the pointer is a void type. As is in Guillaume's example.

Comment: @Armin You don't **have to,** I repeat - the cast can be avoided if you assign the pointer to a temporary.

Comment: @H2CO3 But you **have to** if you don't use a temp , as is shown in his example.

Comment: @Armin That's right, but that's not what I'm saying - I rather suggest that it's not globally inevitable.