# Do I need to create three separate arrays for my assignment?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, dynamic-memory-allocation

Ok firstly I'll explain my assignment. For this assignment I have to use dynamic memory allocation which I am having no problems with. What I am having a problem with is figuring out the correct way to work my assignment. For my assignment I need to create a program that prompt the user to enter how many students they have then ask for the following information; Student ID, Birthdate, and Phone number. I need to use a loop to prompt the user to enter all the students information. I need to create a loop that will scan through all the student IDs and find the oldest student using their birthdate (The loop must be able scan through more then 3 students).

Here is my code, I havent done much in it yet because I'm not sure really where to start. I've already setup the dynamic memory allocation, but I don't know how to work the rest of this. Please help me.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
int * studentData= NULL;

int students;
printf("How many students are you entering records for:\n");
scanf("%d", &students);

studentData=(int*)malloc((sizeof(int)*students));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 3 seperate arrays one for ID, one for DOB and one for phone? If so, then yes you could do it that way. A nicer way might be to use a structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)).

Comment: Oh, also, in C it is normally a good idea to *not* cast the return value of malloc - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a structure:

```
//Define a type, such as int, char, double...
typedef struct studentDataType {
    int ID;
    int birthDateDay;
    int birthDateMonth;
    int birthDateYear;
    int phoneNumber;
};
```

Then create an array, where each of those elements is of type studentData:

```
//Create an array, where each element is of type studentData
studentDataType *studentData = (studentDataType *)malloc(numberOfStudents * sizeof(studentData));
```

Then loop through them with:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfStudents ; ++i) {
    printf("%i %i %i\n", studentData[i].ID, studentData[i].phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Semi-colon missing in `struct` declaration.

Comment: `cout` is C++, not C. You will have to use `printf`

Comment: Sorry, use printf, cout is C++.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what arrayOfStudents is referencing too.

Comment: The arrayOfStudents is the array which contains the data (in your code, I presume studentData is intended to be the same as my arrayOfStudents).

Comment: Ok, thank you I was assuming that but as you can tell I'm still just getting my feet wet in the world of programming. Thanks for the help

Comment: @LordZsolt It doesn't necessary to cast return value of malloc(). Moreover it doesn't give any warnings at all.

Comment: No problem, you'll get used to it. The fact that you're dynamically allocating memory means you're doing quite well :)

Comment: @LordZsolt I replaced *arrayOfStudents w/ *studentData in your second piece of code you provided me. But I'm getting the following error "invalid operands to binary." What do I need to change? Also if you wouldn't mind I would greatly appreciate it if you could change what you provided me with to C format because it's really confusing me lol. Thank you

Comment: @Michael Refer to this thread about why you should cast void* pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986214/why-type-cast-a-void-pointer

Comment: If you simply replace it, it will conflict since studentData is actually the type of your structure (two things have same name). Updated my code so the array is named studentData

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't forget to accept the answer, so others can see the question's been answered.

Comment: @LordZsolt Here is a pure "C". And first answer at your reference link contains another link to a [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following struct. You can make year, month and day as separate fields. It will be simpler for a quick start:

```
struct Student
{
    int studentID; 
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    long long phone; // phone is too large for 32 int
};
```