# function call, casting its void * argument to any other type

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

there is this question on stack overflow
[Why type cast a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986214/why-type-cast-a-void-pointer)
I want to ask relevant question on comment but I don't allow as I am newbie here.
My question is in the second answer given by Guillaume, there is this function.

```
void some_function(void * some_param) {
    int some_value = *((int *) some_param); /* ok */
```

Can I do like this

```
// function defination

void some_function(void * some_param) {
    int some_value = *some_param;

// calling function, casting in argument

some_function((int *) some_param);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this call

```
some_function((int *) some_param);
```

the function argument is implicitly converted to the type of the parameter that is `void *`. So the casting is redundant and this statement within the function

```
int some_value = *some_param;
```

is invalid.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.2 void)

> 1 The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has
>   type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit
>   conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an
>   expression. **If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a
>   void expression, its value or designator is discarded**. (A void
>   expression is evaluated for its side effects.)

And this expression

```
*some_param
```

has the type void within the function

```
void some_function(void * some_param) {
    int some_value = *some_param;
    //...
}
```

As for the question

> During function call, can I cast its void * argument to any other type
>   in ANSI C

You may assign a pointer of the type `void *` to pointer to object of any other type without casting or you may cast a pointer of the type `void *` to any object pointer type..

Comment: @vkchavda There is a mark where questions are up-voted and down-voted.